# How does this array variable reference act?

Tags: java

I was wondering how something like this would work.

```java
int[] a = {5, 3, 4};

int[] b = {3, 4, 5};

a = b;
```

Does this mean that `a` will now reference `b`.
So if I do `a[0]` it will be `3`?

Also if this is the case what happens to the items in the old array?

Comment: how about you compile and run that code? For questions like this, this is the easiest way to get your first question(s) answered.

Comment: *Does this mean that a will now reference b* may be the first thing you need to fix. Let's say *`a` will reference the array object that `b` is currently referencing*, and take it from there.

Comment: @Stultuske How would that answer the question of what happens to the old array?

Comment: @gymguy42 did I say it answers all your questions? No, I said it would answer the first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does this mean that a will now reference b. So if I do a[0] it will be 3?

Sort of. `a` doesn't reference `b` (the variable), it references the same array that `b` refers to. There's no connection between `a` and `b`, it's just that they both refer to the same array (after the `a = b` assignment).

> Also if this is the case what happens to the items in the old array?

The old array is eligible for garbage collection, since nothing refers to it anymore. Since it's an array of primitive values, the items are part of the array, so GC'ing the array inherently means the items are GC'd.

In memory, initially you had:

```
              +−−−−−−−−−+
a:Ref33423−−−>| (Array) |
              +−−−−−−−−−+
              | 5       |
              | 3       |
              | 4       |
              +−−−−−−−−−+

              +−−−−−−−−−+
b:Ref54687−−−>| (Array) |
              +−−−−−−−−−+
              | 3       |
              | 4       |
              | 5       |
              +−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after the `a = b;`, you have:

```
              +−−−−−−−−−+
              | (Array) |
              +−−−−−−−−−+
              | 5       |
              | 3       |
              | 4       |
              +−−−−−−−−−+
a:Ref54687−−+
            |
            |  +−−−−−−−−−+
            +−>| (Array) |
            |  +−−−−−−−−−+
            |  | 3       |
b:Ref54687−−+  | 4       |
               | 5       |
               +−−−−−−−−−+
```

...and eventually GC will remove that orphaned array:

```
a:Ref54687−−+
            |
            |  +−−−−−−−−−+
            +−>| (Array) |
            |  +−−−−−−−−−+
            |  | 3       |
b:Ref54687−−+  | 4       |
               | 5       |
               +−−−−−−−−−+
```

---

I should note that **if** it had been an array of objects, the array and each object the array referred to would potentially have different lifespans, GC'ing the array doesn't necessarily mean the objects in it are GC'd (it depends on whether anything else has references to them).

Comment: Hi TJ, wouldn't the _items_ themselves _not_ be garbage collected, since they are now being referred to by the new array reference?

Comment: To be more accurate:  _"a will now reference b"_ should be : *"`a` will now refer to the array that `b` is referring"* .  In Java you cannot have a reference variable refer to another reference variable (at least not directly).

Comment: @AdrianShum - Yeah, I should have called out that phrasing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Since it's an array of primitives, the items *are* the array.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't understand what you mean: first both array reference `a` and `b` are referring to same array instance.  Second, for array of primitive type, we do not have item allocated from the heap individually

Comment: @gymguy42 - Thanks. I've updated the answer slightly, Tim and Adrian had good points that I've updated to address.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that a will now reference b. So if I do a[0] it will be 3?

Yes, you can think a and b as remote controllers of two TVs. `a=b` means a is pointing where b is pointing. So a[0] will be 3.

> Also if this is the case what happens to the items in the old array?

As there are currently no references to the first array, they're are going to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

> **Yes, now a will refer b and a[0] will be 3.**

Also, now there will be no reference to the old array so it will be eligible for Garbage Collection.

```
    int[] a = {5, 3, 4};
    int[] b = {3, 4, 5};

    System.out.println(a[0]);//5

    a=b;

    System.out.println(a[0]);//3
```